# springmvc @RequestMapping The following two urls How to exact match?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

springmvc @RequestMapping in my code

```
@RequestMapping("/{c1}-{c2}-{c3}-{c4}.htm")
public void category(@PathVariable("c1") Integer c1,@PathVariable("c2") Integer c2,@PathVariable("c3") Integer c3,@PathVariable("c4") Integer c4){
    System.out.println(c1);
    System.out.println(c2);
    System.out.println(c3);
    System.out.println(c4);
}

@RequestMapping("/{c1}-{c2}-{c3}-{c4}-{label}.htm")
public void label(
        @PathVariable("c1") Integer c1,
        @PathVariable("c2") Integer c2,
        @PathVariable("c3") Integer c3,
        @PathVariable("c4") Integer c4,
        @PathVariable("label") Integer label){
    System.out.println(c1);
    System.out.println(c2);
    System.out.println(c3);
    System.out.println(c4);
    System.out.println(label);
}
```

I want url "**/2-5-3-138-8.htm**"  mapping the "**label**" method~

but actual mapping  the "**category**" method
and Parse out the parameters:

- c1:2-5
- c2:3
- c3:138
- c4:8

How can I let this path "**/2-5-3-138-8.htm**"  to match the "**label**" method?

Comment: Can you directly paste the console output here. Because I am just wondering how a "2-5" (which is a string representation) would get casted to Integer (c1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with the patterns updated as follow:

```
@RequestMapping("/{c1:[0-9]+}-{c2:[0-9]+}-{c3:[0-9]+}-{c4:[0-9]+}.htm")
...
@RequestMapping("/{c1:[0-9]+}-{c2:[0-9]+}-{c3:[0-9]+}-{c4:[0-9]+}-{label}.htm")
```